# Can I use an instance variable when chaining methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a show page for the periods controller. What I want to do is show all the registrations for that period.

In my period model I have: `has_many :registrations`, and in my registration model I have `belongs_to :period`

What I want to do is something like this:

```
  <% registrations.@period.each do |registration| %>

  <% end %>
```

That doesn't seem to work though. How can I make this work? and not get the error `syntax error, unexpected tIVAR
    registrations.@period.each do |registration|`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do this. Instance variables are *always* private, you *cannot* access them from outside the instance. The *only way* to interact with an object is by sending it messages.

So, if you want to access an instance variable from the outside, you need to define a getter method for it.

Thankfully, `belongs_to :period` already defines a getter method called `period` for you, so you can use that.

Comment: so, `<% registrations.period.each do |registration| %>` should work then? I get `undefined local variable or method 'registrations' for #<#<Class:0x007ff064edcae0>:0x007ff065452538>`

Comment: Try `@period.registrations.each do ...`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might want is

```
<% @period.registrations.each do |registration| %>

<% end %>
```

In general, if you really want to access instance variables, you can use the `instance_variable_get` method. Yet, in your example it won't work because a) you were trying to call it on an Array and b) associations (`belongs_to`) don't create instance variables.

Comment: But, I am on the periods show page. So do I create a an instance variable in my controller for registrations?